# Programmatically verify SNS topic permission to send messages to SQS (using IAM?)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-iam, amazon-sns

I am currently working in C# but I believe that the issue would be the same in any AWS SDK.

I'm trying to verify programmatically that a topic can send messages to a queue (not actually trying to add the permission, just checking that it's there).

So far the only way I found is by scanning the queue policy for statements that match the topic ARN, i.e..:

```
policy.Statements.Any(
    statement =>
        statement.Effect == Statement.StatementEffect.Allow
        && statement.Principals.Any(
            principal => string.Equals(
                principal.Id,
                Principal.AllUsers.Id,
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        && statement.Actions.Any(
            identifier => string.Equals(
                identifier.ActionName,
                SQSActionIdentifiers.SendMessage.ActionName,
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        && statement.Resources.Any(resource => resource.Id == queueArn)
        && statement.Conditions.Any(
            condition =>
                (string.Equals(
                     condition.Type,
                     ConditionFactory.StringComparisonType.StringLike.ToString(),
                     StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                 || string.Equals(
                     condition.Type,
                     ConditionFactory.StringComparisonType.StringEquals.ToString(),
                     StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                 || string.Equals(
                     condition.Type,
                     ConditionFactory.ArnComparisonType.ArnEquals.ToString(),
                     StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                 || string.Equals(
                     condition.Type,
                     ConditionFactory.ArnComparisonType.ArnLike.ToString(),
                     StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                && string.Equals(
                    condition.ConditionKey,
                    ConditionFactory.SOURCE_ARN_CONDITION_KEY,
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                && condition.Values.Contains(topicArn)))
```

This is by the way similar to how it's done in the AWS SDK when calling SubscribeQueueAsync (see [corresponding code on github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/SimpleNotificationService/Custom/AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient.Extensions.cs)).

My issue with this method is how brittle it feels. For instance what if the condition has wildcard(s)? What if an authorization exists for specific principals instead of all?

So I thought I'd maybe use IAM, specifically [SimulatePrincipalPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_SimulatePrincipalPolicy.html) or [SimulateCustomPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_SimulateCustomPolicy.html). Can they be used for that?

I thought something like this:

```
var simulatePrincipalPolicyRequest = new SimulatePrincipalPolicyRequest
{
    ActionNames = { SQSActionIdentifiers.SendMessage.ActionName },
    ResourceArns = { queueArn },
    PolicySourceArn = topicArn
};

var response = await _iamService.SimulatePrincipalPolicyAsync(
    request: simulatePrincipalPolicyRequest,
    cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Would have worked but I'm getting `Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model.InvalidInputException : Could not extract entity from ARN : arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:<accountid>:<topicname>` as a result.

I thought maybe it had to do with the CallerArn property? I've noticed that the user key that the sender account id seems to be always the same in the messages a queue receives from a topic (AIDA*****************).

Not sure if what I'm trying is possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, you can't use `SimulatePrincipalPolicy` ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/IAM/MIIAMServiceSimulatePrincipalPolicySimulatePrincipalPolicyRequest.html)) to check if a service has an IAM permission:

> The entity can be an IAM user, group, or role. If you specify a user, then the simulation also includes all of the policies that are attached to groups that the user belongs to.

If you look at the `CallerArn` [property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/IAM/TSimulatePrincipalPolicyRequest.html) of the `SimulatePolicyRequest` class you get:

> You can specify only the ARN of an IAM user. You cannot specify the
>   ARN of an assumed role, federated user, or a service principal.

I tested this using powershell SDK - which runs over the .net one and got the same error.

```
Test-IAMPrincipalPolicy -ActionName 'sqs:SendMessage' -PolicySourceArn arn:aws:sns:::sim-test -ResourceArn arn:aws:sqs:::sim-test

Test-IAMPrincipalPolicy : Could not extract entity from ARN : arn:aws:sns:::sim-test
```

**Possible Solution**
The function does work with IAM [Service Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html#iam-term-service-role). You can create a service role in IAM that [delegates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-service.html) permission to SNS to send messages to SQS. If you are in a position to create a service role for SNS, then you will be able to use the SimulatePrincipalPolicy function.

I tested this in PS again. First I created the service role in IAM console:

- Click on Roles in the left hand menu.
- Click Create Role button
- Select AWS service
- Click SNS
- It will only present one use case ("Allow SNS to call CloudWatch") - don't worry about this we can clean it up later.
- Click "Next:Permissions"
- Click "Next:Review"
- Click "Create Role"

You have now delegated some CloudWatch permission to SNS. We will remove this in a sec, but for now I can at least call the function, passing in the policy ARN:

```
Test-IAMPrincipalPolicy -ActionName 'sqs:SendMessage' -PolicySourceArn arn:aws:iam:::role/sim-test-servicerole -ResourceArn arn:aws:sqs:::sim-test

EvalActionName              : sqs:SendMessage
EvalDecision                : implicitDeny
EvalDecisionDetails         : {}
EvalResourceName            : arn:aws:sqs:::sim-test
MatchedStatements           : {}
MissingContextValues        : {}
OrganizationsDecisionDetail :
ResourceSpecificResults     : {arn:aws:sqs:::sim-test}
```

Note that the EvalDecision is implicitDeny.

Now you can edit the created role. Delete the Cloudwatch policy and add the relevant SQS policy and test again:

```
EvalActionName              : sqs:SendMessage
EvalDecision                : allowed
EvalDecisionDetails         : {}
EvalResourceName            : arn:aws:sqs:::sim-test
MatchedStatements           : {AmazonSQSFullAccess}
MissingContextValues        : {}
OrganizationsDecisionDetail :
ResourceSpecificResults     : {arn:aws:sqs:::sim-test}
```

If you can't/won't setup the service role for SNS then I think the only way is to scrape the policy as you have already done.

### Update

After further testing, even though the above gets the function to work, I can't actually get the SNS to land in SQS! So it's a false positive, and I think you are back to scraping the policy.